# Symlinked MAMP Folder Causing 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mamp

I have a folder in my root MAMP directory, "site". I have that symlinked to a folder in ~/Documents/Dropbox/site, so whatever happens in "site" gets transferred to Dropbox.

However, when I do this, I get a 403 forbidden error when trying to view `localhost/site`- is this a problem because I'm using PHP and I should fix php.ini, or is this an httpd.conf problem?

In httpd.conf, I have `AllowOverride` set to `None`.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: In addition to the `FollowSymlinks` answer - do the folder permissions (where the symlink points) allow the httpd user allowed to read that directory?

Comment: I believe so, I get info'd both folders and I made it R&W access for all, no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also the `FollowSymlinks` option in Apache, which is generally disabled by default. You can enable it by doing

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Comment: Is that a .htaccess solution? I'd like to fix the problem with httpd.conf if I can.

Comment: It can go in either. Generally there's no difference between .htaccess and a <Directory> block in httpd.conf, except .htaccess is parsed at each request and doesn't need a server bounce for changes to take effect.

Comment: I added it to the .htaccess file, and I'm still getting 403 forbidden, for some odd reason.

Comment: Is there a default document in the target directory? index.html or index.php type thing?

Comment: Ah- you fixed the issue! I had the `DirectoryIndex` set to loader.php, when it should have been launcher.php.

Comment: Check the apache error log next time. It's very handy in situations like this - has much more info about the problem than the '403' or '500' default pages you get in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, but I had this problem before and while the solution didn't necessarily make a whole lot of sense, it worked for me:

1. `sudo su <username>` to assume the user (eg, if your webserver is running as `nobody`, use `nobody`
2. If #1 is a user whose shell is something similar to `/sbin/nologin`, temporarily use `usermod` to change their shell to something you can use, like `/bin/bash`, *before* sudoing as them
3. Symlink as the user instead of root or whatever user this was done as previously
4. Reset any changes made in #2

Since symlinks are by default 0777, any normal process has read access provided that the destination directory is also of sufficient permissions (0644 would be fine) - for some reason Apache gave me problems with that to.  Once I created the link as the user in question, it worked like a charm.  HTH!

Edit: also, this almost goes without saying, but I'm assuming you verified the link yourself via a terminal to make sure that the link is correct, right?

Comment: How would go about verifying the link? / I followed your instructions, and the symlink seems to be working correctly, however, I'm still getting a 403 forbidden error on `localhost/site`.

Comment: Basically just `cd` into it and make sure that it actually links to what you want it to. :)

Comment: Just so we can see it, can you also paste your vhost definition in the question?  And also maybe a couple examples of commands you're running to symlink (including CWD, etc) so we can get a better picture.

Comment: Thanks for helping- even though it ended up being a silly .htaccess typo :) (I set `DirectoryIndex` to a file that didn't exist, and for some odd reason that triggered a 403 forbidden)

Comment: Nvm, just saw your comment on the other answer - glad you got it working.