# Trouble locating images

Tags: php, mamp

I'm having trouble with missing images on my server. 
I have been developing a site locally using MAMP for a while and now that I have uploaded it to my server the images cannot be found. Firebug tells me "Failed to load the given URL".

The file structure is the exact same as it was locally and the code is also the same.
The php file trying to load the images is in the site's root folder along with the folder "images".
Here is the file structure:   **images/models/dreadfinsl1.jpg**

Here is the page: http://eoghanoloughlin.net/george/index.php

Can anyone help me? It seems like it would be just one of those stupid problems / simple answers but I'm relatively new to this don't have much experience. It was working fine when I was using MAMP.

Comment: Found the problem. Yes it was a permissions issue, which was easily fixed by modifying folder properties in cyberduck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access an image which is in your server with the help of web browser by specifying absolute path of the image....

Like http://eoghanoloughlin.net/images/models/dreadfinsl1.jpg

If you found any image on the browser, try to display the same image on your index page...

I think specifying the file path is being a problem in your application....

Comment: @MakuraYami

Specifying an absolute link doesn't work. It takes me to the right place but gives me a 403 forbidden error, telling me I don't have permission to access. 
This is the example I tried: [http://eoghanoloughlin.net/george/images/models/dreadfinsl1.jpg](http://eoghanoloughlin.net/george/images/models/dreadfinsl1.jpg)

Do I have to modify permissions myself in the control panel?

Comment: @EoghanOLoughlin, When you create the directory, make sure you set the ownership, mkdir("dir and path", 0755), to allow web users to save and read from them.

before saving the uploaded file, change the permissions of the file, chmod("filename",0666),

Comment: @EoghanOLoughlin, to over ride 403 problem, please go through this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343665/symlinked-mamp-folder-causing-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your in the /george/ map on the server, and i assume locally u used www/

try /george/images/models/dreadfinsl1.jpg

else you will have to use full path http://eoghanoloughlin.net/george/images/models/dreadfinsl1.jpg